# scripting to do a task in PC software

Tags: scripting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTPM7.png)

how can i use scripting to use my Software to delete the records of the specified date? 
i'm quite new at scripts. there are 433 records which i have to do 1 by 1. which will take ages to complete. so i need a way to do it automatically.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
@echo off
C:/DRSAPPS/DATAENTRYINVENTORY.EXE STOCKADj

Echo.
exit
```

have written a batch file to open the .exe file but need to execute it to delete the records that are shown in the picture above.

Comment: Is there even a CLI on that system you are using? A way you can fetch the IDs of records and command things to happen to them or whatever? Your question as is is too broad.

Comment: You can use https://autohotkey.com/ to do some automation in case, when there's no possibility to pass command line arguments.